# What port number should I use

Tags: java, networking, port

I am building a program that will create a socket and have it try and access a outside server not on the local network. For example, I would like to have it accept a IP address of say google.com and then return the hostName for the google.com IP address i would be using to do the request with.

The second program I am going to be writing is going to be doing this

> Write a stream-based echo server and a client sending messages to it,
>   and receiving back each message in turn.

For these two programs, are there a specific ports I should be using to do these specific problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port numbers 0 to 1024 are reserved for privileged services and designated as well-known ports. 
take a look at this link might be helpful.
https://www.webopedia.com/quick_ref/portnumbers.asp

Comment: Okay, I have seen this but I guess I do not understand what the correct port would be in this situation or how i determine the correct one.

Comment: you can use anyone pick 3000 and 3001 for example, but make sure you are using a port that is not used by another program, or it can cause an exception. Also for better practice close the sockets after the program ends.

Comment: @JeffreyHennen basically, you can use literally any port number >1023, as long as you're consistent. For example, I like to use 4444. You can use whatever port number you want.